# One Domain, Two Installs of WordPress

Tags: multisite, directory, subdomains

I'm looking into an upcoming project of a redesign of an existing website. The plan is to install one single installation of WordPress at domain.com. The admin area will be locked down and accessible only to individuals inside the organization's network.

There is a subsection of the site that needs to exist to allow for other individuals outside of the organization to create and publish content. I'd like to set up a separate multisite install of WordPress at subdomain.domain.com. This multisite would be installed with subdirectories so each site will be at subdomain.domain.com/site1 and subdomain.domain.com/site2, etc.

As far as I've read, all of this should work fine with WordPress. The reason we would like to keep two separate installs is simply for security so the base install of wordpress on domain.com isn't accessible in anyway from external sources. I'm just curious if anyone has any experience with this set up or sees any potential pitfalls.

Comment: Of course you can do that.  What is stopping you from setting up two different servers, one for each site?  You dont mention if you require both to be on the same server... which can be done but could have some potential issues.

Comment: @user42826, thinking of any particular problems? I can think of no reason that a WordPress installation and a WordPress multisite installation couldn't exist on the same server (if this is indeed what rmlumley is suggesting) with different site roots... Off the top of my head it sounds fine.

Comment: The problem with one server is if you have one or two IP addresses.  If you only have one IP address, you will run into problems with https/certificates/resolving WP instances.

Comment: Perhaps, but rmlumley makes no mention of SSL certificates or HTTPS in his question. Furthermore it is both entirely possible and practical to assign multiple IP addresses to a single server and give them different site-roots. He additionally seems to imply that the multi-site installation will reside at `subdomain.domain.com` while the non-multisite installation will reside at `domain.com` - there should be no issues resolving the proper WP instance.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm not entirely sure yet about one server vs two. I'd probably leave that up to our network team to determine which is most secure in this scenario. Since the sites at subdomain.domain.com would be exposed to external editors, we'd just want to make sure they had two different mysql databases. Essentially, I want to make sure that IF something did occur on subdomain.domain.com, the install and data on domain.com would be untouched.